# Return LEFT value even if RIGHT value doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to minimize the number of queries made in my application. In this case I need to look up the properties of a chat server by its id, and find any "live stream" from another table with the associated server id that has a "start time" value but a null "end time" value (indicating that the live stream is still in progress). If no live stream is in progress, then no "end time" value will be null, but I still need the properties of that server.

Essentially:

### Lookup server properties and find a live stream:

- If there is no live stream (no null end time), do something with the server properties
- Else, If there is a live stream (an entry with a null end time), tell the user

```sql
SELECT t1.properties
FROM t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_streams 
ON t1.serverID = t2.serverID 
WHERE t1.serverID = '<id>';
```

...returns and endtime of null if t2 is totally empty, which is good, but all rows if it's not, which is bad.

```sql
SELECT t1.properties
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_streams
ON t1.serverID = t2.serverID
WHERE t1.serverID = '<id>'
AND t2.endtime IS NULL;
```

...returns nothing if no live stream is active (no row has a null endtime), but needs to at least return the t1.properties anyways.

Basically I'm trying to create a new "live stream" using the "server properties" if there is no live stream currently active.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like this:

```
SELECT t1.properties
FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     t_streams t2
     ON t1.serverID = t2.serverID
WHERE t1.serverID = '<id>'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN t2.endtime IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         t2.endtime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This returns one matching row with a preference for the `endtime` being `NULL`.